# Moving average over a dataset

Tags: plotting, smoothing, averages

I have this data set in .csv and I imported them to mathematica to analyze them using Import function. Now here I have only shown a part of the dataset just to give an example of how it looks in Excel.

[image]

Basically there is DrainI(i), DrainV(i), GateI(i), GateV(i) where GateV(i) is constant for =1,2,3,4....

Now I want to export this into Mathematica notebook and essentially plot DrainI(i) v/s DrainV(i) for different GateV(i) in the same plot.

This is how I do it:

```
ds = Import["ExampleData.csv", "Dataset", 
   HeaderLines -> 1];
keypairs = {{"DrainV(1)", "DrainI(1)"}, {"DrainV(2)", 
    "DrainI(2)"}, {"DrainV(3)", "DrainI(3)"}, {"DrainV(4)", 
    "DrainI(4)"}, {"DrainV(5)", "DrainI(5)"}, {"DrainV(6)", 
    "DrainI(6)"}, {"DrainV(7)", "DrainI(7)"}, {"DrainV(8)", 
    "DrainI(8)"}, {"DrainV(9)", "DrainI(9)"}, {"DrainV(10)", 
    "DrainI(10)"}, {"DrainV(11)", "DrainI(11)"}};
idvd = Normal@ds[Values@*Transpose, keypairs];
idvdnew = 
  MapAt[#*20 &, 
   idvd, {All, All, 2}]; (*Convert to A/mm*)
ListLinePlot[idvdnew , 
 PlotLegends -> Defer /@ keypairs, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(DS\)]\)(V)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(d\)]\)(A/mm)"}, PlotRange -> All, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 15} , ImageSize -> 400, 
 FrameStyle -> Black]
```

The original dataset ExampleData.csv is given below:

```
DrainI(1),DrainV(1),GateI(1),GateV(1),DrainI(2),DrainV(2),GateI(2),GateV(2),DrainI(3),DrainV(3),GateI(3),GateV(3),DrainI(4),DrainV(4),GateI(4),GateV(4),DrainI(5),DrainV(5),GateI(5),GateV(5),DrainI(6),DrainV(6),GateI(6),GateV(6),DrainI(7),DrainV(7),GateI(7),GateV(7),DrainI(8),DrainV(8),GateI(8),GateV(8),DrainI(9),DrainV(9),GateI(9),GateV(9),DrainI(10),DrainV(10),GateI(10),GateV(10),DrainI(11),DrainV(11),GateI(11),GateV(11)
5.35E-10,0.00E+00,2.45E-06,-8.00E+00,5.11E-10,0.00E+00,1.44E-06,-7.00E+00,2.94E-10,0.00E+00,2.19E-06,-6.00E+00,1.87E-09,0.00E+00,3.45E-06,-5.00E+00,2.54E-09,0.00E+00,1.69E-06,-4.00E+00,3.06E-09,0.00E+00,1.94E-06,-3.00E+00,3.21E-09,0.00E+00,3.20E-06,-3.00E+00,3.50E-09,0.00E+00,1.18E-06,-1.00E+00,3.71E-09,0.00E+00,2.19E-06,0.00E+00,3.67E-09,0.00E+00,1.18E-06,1.00E+00,-4.08E-07,0.00E+00,1.63E-05,2.00E+00
5.86E-10,2.50E-01,1.69E-06,-8.00E+00,4.16E-10,2.50E-01,2.95E-06,-7.00E+00,4.04E-10,2.50E-01,2.70E-06,-6.00E+00,4.51E-06,2.50E-01,2.70E-06,-5.00E+00,6.45E-06,2.50E-01,2.45E-06,-4.00E+00,7.15E-06,2.50E-01,3.96E-06,-3.00E+00,7.39E-06,2.50E-01,1.44E-06,-3.00E+00,7.66E-06,2.50E-01,2.70E-06,-1.00E+00,7.79E-06,2.50E-01,2.19E-06,0.00E+00,7.87E-06,2.50E-01,2.95E-06,1.00E+00,3.34E-06,2.50E-01,1.51E-05,2.00E+00
6.38E-10,5.00E-01,2.45E-06,-8.00E+00,4.72E-10,5.00E-01,2.45E-06,-7.00E+00,4.35E-10,5.00E-01,1.18E-06,-6.00E+00,1.20E-05,5.00E-01,1.69E-06,-5.00E+00,2.30E-05,5.00E-01,1.44E-06,-4.00E+00,2.65E-05,5.00E-01,1.44E-06,-3.00E+00,2.79E-05,5.00E-01,1.69E-06,-3.00E+00,2.90E-05,5.00E-01,2.45E-06,-1.00E+00,2.94E-05,5.00E-01,3.71E-06,0.00E+00,3.01E-05,5.00E-01,2.95E-06,1.00E+00,2.62E-05,5.00E-01,8.75E-06,2.00E+00
6.84E-10,7.50E-01,1.94E-06,-8.00E+00,4.82E-10,7.50E-01,3.45E-06,-7.00E+00,5.12E-10,7.50E-01,2.45E-06,-6.00E+00,1.66E-05,7.50E-01,2.95E-06,-5.00E+00,4.50E-05,7.50E-01,2.45E-06,-4.00E+00,5.35E-05,7.50E-01,1.94E-06,-3.00E+00,5.74E-05,7.50E-01,3.20E-06,-3.00E+00,6.00E-05,7.50E-01,2.70E-06,-1.00E+00,6.15E-05,7.50E-01,2.45E-06,0.00E+00,6.33E-05,7.50E-01,2.45E-06,1.00E+00,6.22E-05,7.50E-01,3.20E-06,2.00E+00
4.54E-10,1.00E+00,2.70E-06,-8.00E+00,5.56E-10,1.00E+00,1.69E-06,-7.00E+00,6.86E-10,1.00E+00,1.18E-06,-6.00E+00,1.84E-05,1.00E+00,3.20E-06,-5.00E+00,6.74E-05,1.00E+00,2.95E-06,-4.00E+00,8.66E-05,1.00E+00,2.45E-06,-3.00E+00,9.44E-05,1.00E+00,1.94E-06,-3.00E+00,9.91E-05,1.00E+00,2.19E-06,-1.00E+00,1.02E-04,1.00E+00,1.69E-06,0.00E+00,1.05E-04,1.00E+00,2.45E-06,1.00E+00,1.04E-04,1.00E+00,2.95E-06,2.00E+00
5.49E-10,1.25E+00,2.19E-06,-8.00E+00,6.15E-10,1.25E+00,3.45E-06,-7.00E+00,4.43E-10,1.25E+00,3.45E-06,-6.00E+00,1.93E-05,1.25E+00,2.45E-06,-5.00E+00,8.90E-05,1.25E+00,2.19E-06,-4.00E+00,1.22E-04,1.25E+00,1.69E-06,-3.00E+00,1.35E-04,1.25E+00,2.45E-06,-3.00E+00,1.43E-04,1.25E+00,1.18E-06,-1.00E+00,1.47E-04,1.25E+00,2.95E-06,0.00E+00,1.52E-04,1.25E+00,2.95E-06,1.00E+00,1.50E-04,1.25E+00,2.95E-06,2.00E+00
5.01E-10,1.50E+00,1.18E-06,-8.00E+00,6.72E-10,1.50E+00,3.71E-06,-7.00E+00,5.66E-10,1.50E+00,2.95E-06,-6.00E+00,2.01E-05,1.50E+00,3.20E-06,-5.00E+00,1.06E-04,1.50E+00,2.45E-06,-4.00E+00,1.58E-04,1.50E+00,6.80E-07,-3.00E+00,1.79E-04,1.50E+00,2.45E-06,-3.00E+00,1.90E-04,1.50E+00,2.70E-06,-1.00E+00,1.96E-04,1.50E+00,2.95E-06,0.00E+00,2.02E-04,1.50E+00,2.95E-06,1.00E+00,1.99E-04,1.50E+00,1.69E-06,2.00E+00
4.91E-10,1.75E+00,2.95E-06,-8.00E+00,7.20E-10,1.75E+00,2.45E-06,-7.00E+00,9.32E-10,1.75E+00,2.70E-06,-6.00E+00,2.10E-05,1.75E+00,2.45E-06,-5.00E+00,1.17E-04,1.75E+00,1.69E-06,-4.00E+00,1.92E-04,1.75E+00,3.71E-06,-3.00E+00,2.22E-04,1.75E+00,3.20E-06,-3.00E+00,2.37E-04,1.75E+00,2.70E-06,-1.00E+00,2.45E-04,1.75E+00,9.33E-07,0.00E+00,2.54E-04,1.75E+00,1.69E-06,1.00E+00,2.49E-04,1.75E+00,1.18E-06,2.00E+00
5.11E-10,2.00E+00,3.20E-06,-8.00E+00,7.66E-10,2.00E+00,1.18E-06,-7.00E+00,1.45E-09,2.00E+00,2.19E-06,-6.00E+00,2.24E-05,2.00E+00,1.94E-06,-5.00E+00,1.24E-04,2.00E+00,1.94E-06,-4.00E+00,2.24E-04,2.00E+00,1.44E-06,-3.00E+00,2.67E-04,2.00E+00,2.95E-06,-3.00E+00,2.84E-04,2.00E+00,1.69E-06,-1.00E+00,2.96E-04,2.00E+00,9.33E-07,0.00E+00,3.06E-04,2.00E+00,2.95E-06,1.00E+00,3.01E-04,2.00E+00,9.33E-07,2.00E+00
7.07E-10,2.25E+00,1.94E-06,-8.00E+00,4.76E-10,2.25E+00,9.33E-07,-7.00E+00,1.67E-09,2.25E+00,2.19E-06,-6.00E+00,2.38E-05,2.25E+00,1.69E-06,-5.00E+00,1.28E-04,2.25E+00,2.70E-06,-4.00E+00,2.51E-04,2.25E+00,2.19E-06,-3.00E+00,3.08E-04,2.25E+00,2.45E-06,-3.00E+00,3.31E-04,2.25E+00,1.44E-06,-1.00E+00,3.46E-04,2.25E+00,2.70E-06,0.00E+00,3.57E-04,2.25E+00,9.33E-07,1.00E+00,3.50E-04,2.25E+00,2.70E-06,2.00E+00
6.95E-10,2.50E+00,2.19E-06,-8.00E+00,8.37E-10,2.50E+00,2.70E-06,-7.00E+00,1.71E-09,2.50E+00,1.94E-06,-6.00E+00,2.49E-05,2.50E+00,2.45E-06,-5.00E+00,1.31E-04,2.50E+00,3.96E-06,-4.00E+00,2.74E-04,2.50E+00,2.19E-06,-3.00E+00,3.48E-04,2.50E+00,1.69E-06,-2.00E+00,3.79E-04,2.50E+00,1.18E-06,-1.00E+00,3.97E-04,2.50E+00,1.18E-06,0.00E+00,4.07E-04,2.50E+00,2.95E-06,1.00E+00,4.03E-04,2.50E+00,2.45E-06,2.00E+00
5.78E-10,2.75E+00,2.70E-06,-8.00E+00,4.97E-10,2.75E+00,1.18E-06,-7.00E+00,1.98E-09,2.75E+00,1.94E-06,-6.00E+00,2.62E-05,2.75E+00,2.95E-06,-5.00E+00,1.34E-04,2.75E+00,3.20E-06,-4.00E+00,2.91E-04,2.75E+00,1.94E-06,-3.00E+00,3.85E-04,2.75E+00,2.70E-06,-2.00E+00,4.23E-04,2.75E+00,2.45E-06,-1.00E+00,4.44E-04,2.75E+00,2.70E-06,0.00E+00,4.54E-04,2.75E+00,1.94E-06,1.00E+00,4.51E-04,2.75E+00,3.20E-06,2.00E+00
5.41E-10,3.00E+00,2.70E-06,-8.00E+00,6.10E-10,3.00E+00,1.94E-06,-7.00E+00,2.83E-09,3.00E+00,1.69E-06,-6.00E+00,2.69E-05,3.00E+00,3.20E-06,-5.00E+00,1.36E-04,3.00E+00,3.45E-06,-4.00E+00,3.05E-04,3.00E+00,1.69E-06,-3.00E+00,4.19E-04,3.00E+00,3.71E-06,-2.00E+00,4.62E-04,3.00E+00,2.19E-06,-1.00E+00,4.88E-04,3.00E+00,2.45E-06,0.00E+00,4.96E-04,3.00E+00,2.70E-06,1.00E+00,4.95E-04,3.00E+00,4.21E-06,2.00E+00
5.47E-10,3.25E+00,2.19E-06,-8.00E+00,5.40E-10,3.25E+00,2.95E-06,-7.00E+00,4.86E-09,3.25E+00,1.69E-06,-6.00E+00,2.73E-05,3.25E+00,2.19E-06,-5.00E+00,1.40E-04,3.25E+00,2.95E-06,-4.00E+00,3.15E-04,3.25E+00,1.94E-06,-3.00E+00,4.46E-04,3.25E+00,2.45E-06,-2.00E+00,4.99E-04,3.25E+00,2.70E-06,-1.00E+00,5.15E-04,3.25E+00,1.94E-06,0.00E+00,5.22E-04,3.25E+00,3.71E-06,1.00E+00,5.19E-04,3.25E+00,2.45E-06,2.00E+00
6.16E-10,3.50E+00,2.70E-06,-8.00E+00,5.18E-10,3.50E+00,1.44E-06,-7.00E+00,7.17E-09,3.50E+00,2.70E-06,-6.00E+00,2.78E-05,3.50E+00,1.94E-06,-5.00E+00,1.45E-04,3.50E+00,1.94E-06,-4.00E+00,3.22E-04,3.50E+00,3.45E-06,-3.00E+00,4.68E-04,3.50E+00,1.69E-06,-2.00E+00,5.21E-04,3.50E+00,2.19E-06,-1.00E+00,5.57E-04,3.50E+00,2.45E-06,0.00E+00,5.66E-04,3.50E+00,3.45E-06,1.00E+00,5.60E-04,3.50E+00,2.70E-06,2.00E+00
9.05E-10,3.75E+00,2.45E-06,-8.00E+00,5.36E-10,3.75E+00,2.70E-06,-7.00E+00,8.24E-09,3.75E+00,1.44E-06,-6.00E+00,2.81E-05,3.75E+00,2.45E-06,-5.00E+00,1.49E-04,3.75E+00,3.45E-06,-4.00E+00,3.27E-04,3.75E+00,3.71E-06,-3.00E+00,4.82E-04,3.75E+00,2.19E-06,-2.00E+00,5.54E-04,3.75E+00,2.70E-06,-1.00E+00,5.92E-04,3.75E+00,3.20E-06,0.00E+00,6.04E-04,3.75E+00,2.19E-06,1.00E+00,6.02E-04,3.75E+00,2.19E-06,2.00E+00
8.55E-10,4.00E+00,1.94E-06,-8.00E+00,6.19E-10,4.00E+00,2.70E-06,-7.00E+00,6.61E-09,4.00E+00,2.19E-06,-6.00E+00,2.85E-05,4.00E+00,2.95E-06,-5.00E+00,1.53E-04,4.00E+00,2.19E-06,-4.00E+00,3.30E-04,4.00E+00,2.45E-06,-3.00E+00,4.92E-04,4.00E+00,1.69E-06,-2.00E+00,5.83E-04,4.00E+00,2.19E-06,-1.00E+00,6.24E-04,4.00E+00,3.20E-06,0.00E+00,6.39E-04,4.00E+00,2.70E-06,1.00E+00,6.40E-04,4.00E+00,2.19E-06,2.00E+00
7.16E-10,4.25E+00,3.20E-06,-8.00E+00,8.72E-10,4.25E+00,1.94E-06,-7.00E+00,7.40E-09,4.25E+00,3.20E-06,-6.00E+00,2.90E-05,4.25E+00,9.33E-07,-5.00E+00,1.57E-04,4.25E+00,2.45E-06,-4.00E+00,3.32E-04,4.25E+00,2.95E-06,-3.00E+00,4.99E-04,4.25E+00,2.19E-06,-2.00E+00,6.09E-04,4.25E+00,1.94E-06,-1.00E+00,6.54E-04,4.25E+00,2.19E-06,0.00E+00,6.74E-04,4.25E+00,2.45E-06,1.00E+00,6.78E-04,4.25E+00,2.70E-06,2.00E+00
6.96E-10,4.50E+00,2.19E-06,-8.00E+00,8.47E-10,4.50E+00,3.20E-06,-7.00E+00,9.12E-09,4.50E+00,3.45E-06,-6.00E+00,2.93E-05,4.50E+00,1.69E-06,-5.00E+00,1.57E-04,4.50E+00,1.69E-06,-4.00E+00,3.33E-04,4.50E+00,2.70E-06,-3.00E+00,5.04E-04,4.50E+00,2.45E-06,-2.00E+00,6.27E-04,4.50E+00,2.45E-06,-1.00E+00,6.81E-04,4.50E+00,1.44E-06,0.00E+00,7.09E-04,4.50E+00,2.70E-06,1.00E+00,7.14E-04,4.50E+00,1.94E-06,2.00E+00
6.93E-10,4.75E+00,2.19E-06,-8.00E+00,7.24E-10,4.75E+00,1.94E-06,-7.00E+00,9.81E-09,4.75E+00,3.45E-06,-6.00E+00,2.96E-05,4.75E+00,1.44E-06,-5.00E+00,1.58E-04,4.75E+00,2.95E-06,-4.00E+00,3.35E-04,4.75E+00,2.70E-06,-3.00E+00,5.08E-04,4.75E+00,2.45E-06,-2.00E+00,6.41E-04,4.75E+00,1.69E-06,-1.00E+00,7.04E-04,4.75E+00,2.19E-06,0.00E+00,7.42E-04,4.75E+00,9.33E-07,1.00E+00,7.46E-04,4.75E+00,3.45E-06,2.00E+00
1.05E-09,5.00E+00,3.20E-06,-8.00E+00,7.17E-10,5.00E+00,1.69E-06,-7.00E+00,1.13E-08,5.00E+00,2.45E-06,-6.00E+00,3.00E-05,5.00E+00,1.69E-06,-5.00E+00,1.59E-04,5.00E+00,3.20E-06,-4.00E+00,3.37E-04,5.00E+00,3.20E-06,-3.00E+00,5.10E-04,5.00E+00,2.95E-06,-2.00E+00,6.50E-04,5.00E+00,2.45E-06,-1.00E+00,7.25E-04,5.00E+00,2.95E-06,0.00E+00,7.73E-04,5.00E+00,3.45E-06,1.00E+00,7.80E-04,5.00E+00,9.33E-07,2.00E+00
1.15E-09,5.25E+00,2.70E-06,-8.00E+00,7.25E-10,5.25E+00,3.20E-06,-7.00E+00,1.63E-08,5.25E+00,2.95E-06,-6.00E+00,3.10E-05,5.25E+00,2.95E-06,-5.00E+00,1.59E-04,5.25E+00,2.45E-06,-4.00E+00,3.39E-04,5.25E+00,1.94E-06,-3.00E+00,5.16E-04,5.25E+00,2.45E-06,-2.00E+00,6.51E-04,5.25E+00,2.70E-06,-1.00E+00,7.40E-04,5.25E+00,2.19E-06,0.00E+00,8.02E-04,5.25E+00,2.19E-06,1.00E+00,8.10E-04,5.25E+00,1.94E-06,2.00E+00
9.22E-10,5.50E+00,2.45E-06,-8.00E+00,1.08E-09,5.50E+00,2.70E-06,-7.00E+00,2.12E-08,5.50E+00,1.94E-06,-6.00E+00,3.25E-05,5.50E+00,1.69E-06,-5.00E+00,1.60E-04,5.50E+00,2.19E-06,-4.00E+00,3.41E-04,5.50E+00,2.19E-06,-3.00E+00,5.23E-04,5.50E+00,2.45E-06,-2.00E+00,6.53E-04,5.50E+00,2.45E-06,-1.00E+00,7.54E-04,5.50E+00,2.95E-06,0.00E+00,8.29E-04,5.50E+00,2.45E-06,1.00E+00,8.42E-04,5.50E+00,1.44E-06,2.00E+00
8.66E-10,5.75E+00,3.20E-06,-8.00E+00,1.19E-09,5.75E+00,2.45E-06,-7.00E+00,2.63E-08,5.75E+00,2.70E-06,-6.00E+00,3.39E-05,5.75E+00,2.70E-06,-5.00E+00,1.60E-04,5.75E+00,2.70E-06,-4.00E+00,3.42E-04,5.75E+00,2.19E-06,-3.00E+00,5.30E-04,5.75E+00,1.94E-06,-2.00E+00,6.56E-04,5.75E+00,2.45E-06,-1.00E+00,7.60E-04,5.75E+00,2.19E-06,0.00E+00,8.48E-04,5.75E+00,2.70E-06,1.00E+00,8.68E-04,5.75E+00,3.45E-06,2.00E+00
8.43E-10,6.00E+00,2.45E-06,-8.00E+00,9.71E-10,6.00E+00,2.70E-06,-7.00E+00,2.65E-08,6.00E+00,2.70E-06,-6.00E+00,3.51E-05,6.00E+00,2.70E-06,-5.00E+00,1.61E-04,6.00E+00,3.20E-06,-4.00E+00,3.50E-04,6.00E+00,2.95E-06,-3.00E+00,5.36E-04,6.00E+00,1.69E-06,-2.00E+00,6.57E-04,6.00E+00,2.45E-06,-1.00E+00,7.70E-04,6.00E+00,3.20E-06,0.00E+00,8.60E-04,6.00E+00,1.18E-06,1.00E+00,8.93E-04,6.00E+00,1.94E-06,2.00E+00
1.18E-09,6.25E+00,1.69E-06,-8.00E+00,9.13E-10,6.25E+00,2.95E-06,-7.00E+00,2.64E-08,6.25E+00,2.45E-06,-6.00E+00,3.62E-05,6.25E+00,2.70E-06,-5.00E+00,1.62E-04,6.25E+00,1.94E-06,-4.00E+00,3.58E-04,6.25E+00,2.45E-06,-3.00E+00,5.40E-04,6.25E+00,1.18E-06,-2.00E+00,6.57E-04,6.25E+00,1.94E-06,-1.00E+00,7.76E-04,6.25E+00,1.18E-06,0.00E+00,8.73E-04,6.25E+00,2.70E-06,1.00E+00,9.15E-04,6.25E+00,2.95E-06,2.00E+00
1.40E-09,6.50E+00,1.94E-06,-8.00E+00,9.12E-10,6.50E+00,2.19E-06,-7.00E+00,2.61E-08,6.50E+00,2.95E-06,-6.00E+00,3.62E-05,6.50E+00,2.19E-06,-5.00E+00,1.63E-04,6.50E+00,1.69E-06,-4.00E+00,3.64E-04,6.50E+00,4.21E-06,-3.00E+00,5.44E-04,6.50E+00,2.19E-06,-2.00E+00,6.58E-04,6.50E+00,1.94E-06,-1.00E+00,7.79E-04,6.50E+00,1.94E-06,0.00E+00,8.82E-04,6.50E+00,2.45E-06,1.00E+00,9.36E-04,6.50E+00,1.69E-06,2.00E+00
1.14E-09,6.75E+00,3.71E-06,-8.00E+00,1.22E-09,6.75E+00,2.45E-06,-7.00E+00,2.66E-08,6.75E+00,1.44E-06,-6.00E+00,3.62E-05,6.75E+00,2.95E-06,-5.00E+00,1.68E-04,6.75E+00,3.20E-06,-4.00E+00,3.69E-04,6.75E+00,3.45E-06,-3.00E+00,5.42E-04,6.75E+00,2.95E-06,-2.00E+00,6.59E-04,6.75E+00,1.69E-06,-1.00E+00,7.81E-04,6.75E+00,1.94E-06,0.00E+00,8.88E-04,6.75E+00,2.45E-06,1.00E+00,9.52E-04,6.75E+00,2.95E-06,2.00E+00
1.04E-09,7.00E+00,1.94E-06,-8.00E+00,1.46E-09,7.00E+00,2.70E-06,-7.00E+00,2.74E-08,7.00E+00,2.45E-06,-6.00E+00,3.62E-05,7.00E+00,1.94E-06,-5.00E+00,1.72E-04,7.00E+00,2.70E-06,-4.00E+00,3.71E-04,7.00E+00,2.19E-06,-3.00E+00,5.42E-04,7.00E+00,2.95E-06,-2.00E+00,6.60E-04,7.00E+00,1.69E-06,-1.00E+00,7.83E-04,7.00E+00,2.70E-06,0.00E+00,8.87E-04,7.00E+00,3.20E-06,1.00E+00,9.70E-04,7.00E+00,3.20E-06,2.00E+00
1.02E-09,7.25E+00,2.45E-06,-8.00E+00,1.22E-09,7.25E+00,3.20E-06,-7.00E+00,2.85E-08,7.25E+00,2.70E-06,-6.00E+00,3.63E-05,7.25E+00,3.71E-06,-5.00E+00,1.75E-04,7.25E+00,2.70E-06,-4.00E+00,3.69E-04,7.25E+00,2.95E-06,-3.00E+00,5.40E-04,7.25E+00,2.19E-06,-2.00E+00,6.60E-04,7.25E+00,2.70E-06,-1.00E+00,7.78E-04,7.25E+00,1.94E-06,0.00E+00,8.90E-04,7.25E+00,2.70E-06,1.00E+00,9.86E-04,7.25E+00,3.96E-06,2.00E+00
1.18E-09,7.50E+00,1.69E-06,-8.00E+00,1.14E-09,7.50E+00,2.70E-06,-7.00E+00,2.90E-08,7.50E+00,2.45E-06,-6.00E+00,3.63E-05,7.50E+00,2.70E-06,-5.00E+00,1.78E-04,7.50E+00,2.95E-06,-4.00E+00,3.69E-04,7.50E+00,3.71E-06,-3.00E+00,5.40E-04,7.50E+00,3.45E-06,-2.00E+00,6.67E-04,7.50E+00,2.95E-06,-1.00E+00,7.78E-04,7.50E+00,1.18E-06,0.00E+00,8.88E-04,7.50E+00,3.45E-06,1.00E+00,9.92E-04,7.50E+00,2.19E-06,2.00E+00
1.59E-09,7.75E+00,2.70E-06,-8.00E+00,1.12E-09,7.75E+00,2.45E-06,-7.00E+00,3.71E-08,7.75E+00,2.70E-06,-6.00E+00,3.64E-05,7.75E+00,1.94E-06,-5.00E+00,1.80E-04,7.75E+00,3.45E-06,-4.00E+00,3.67E-04,7.75E+00,2.70E-06,-3.00E+00,5.41E-04,7.75E+00,2.45E-06,-2.00E+00,6.73E-04,7.75E+00,2.45E-06,-1.00E+00,7.79E-04,7.75E+00,2.45E-06,0.00E+00,8.87E-04,7.75E+00,1.44E-06,1.00E+00,1.00E-03,7.75E+00,1.94E-06,2.00E+00
1.41E-09,8.00E+00,3.20E-06,-8.00E+00,1.25E-09,8.00E+00,9.33E-07,-7.00E+00,6.86E-08,8.00E+00,2.19E-06,-6.00E+00,3.67E-05,8.00E+00,1.69E-06,-5.00E+00,1.79E-04,8.00E+00,2.95E-06,-4.00E+00,3.67E-04,8.00E+00,1.94E-06,-3.00E+00,5.41E-04,8.00E+00,2.95E-06,-2.00E+00,6.78E-04,8.00E+00,2.95E-06,-1.00E+00,7.76E-04,8.00E+00,3.20E-06,0.00E+00,8.92E-04,8.00E+00,2.45E-06,1.00E+00,1.00E-03,8.00E+00,2.70E-06,2.00E+00
1.22E-09,8.25E+00,2.19E-06,-8.00E+00,1.68E-09,8.25E+00,2.70E-06,-7.00E+00,7.82E-08,8.25E+00,2.70E-06,-6.00E+00,3.69E-05,8.25E+00,1.94E-06,-5.00E+00,1.79E-04,8.25E+00,1.44E-06,-4.00E+00,3.67E-04,8.25E+00,1.69E-06,-3.00E+00,5.41E-04,8.25E+00,2.70E-06,-2.00E+00,6.82E-04,8.25E+00,1.94E-06,-1.00E+00,7.76E-04,8.25E+00,2.70E-06,0.00E+00,8.97E-04,8.25E+00,1.94E-06,1.00E+00,9.97E-04,8.25E+00,2.45E-06,2.00E+00
1.20E-09,8.50E+00,2.70E-06,-8.00E+00,1.52E-09,8.50E+00,3.20E-06,-7.00E+00,8.73E-08,8.50E+00,2.95E-06,-6.00E+00,3.71E-05,8.50E+00,4.21E-06,-5.00E+00,1.79E-04,8.50E+00,1.44E-06,-4.00E+00,3.67E-04,8.50E+00,1.94E-06,-3.00E+00,5.43E-04,8.50E+00,2.70E-06,-2.00E+00,6.83E-04,8.50E+00,1.69E-06,-1.00E+00,7.76E-04,8.50E+00,3.71E-06,0.00E+00,8.96E-04,8.50E+00,3.45E-06,1.00E+00,9.93E-04,8.50E+00,1.94E-06,2.00E+00
1.20E-09,8.75E+00,2.19E-06,-8.00E+00,1.35E-09,8.75E+00,2.19E-06,-7.00E+00,8.81E-08,8.75E+00,2.19E-06,-6.00E+00,3.86E-05,8.75E+00,2.95E-06,-5.00E+00,1.78E-04,8.75E+00,2.95E-06,-4.00E+00,3.68E-04,8.75E+00,1.69E-06,-3.00E+00,5.42E-04,8.75E+00,2.19E-06,-2.00E+00,6.78E-04,8.75E+00,2.95E-06,-1.00E+00,7.78E-04,8.75E+00,2.45E-06,0.00E+00,8.99E-04,8.75E+00,2.95E-06,1.00E+00,9.86E-04,8.75E+00,2.45E-06,2.00E+00
1.78E-09,9.00E+00,1.69E-06,-8.00E+00,1.32E-09,9.00E+00,2.19E-06,-7.00E+00,8.69E-08,9.00E+00,9.33E-07,-6.00E+00,4.02E-05,9.00E+00,1.94E-06,-5.00E+00,1.79E-04,9.00E+00,2.70E-06,-4.00E+00,3.67E-04,9.00E+00,2.45E-06,-3.00E+00,5.51E-04,9.00E+00,4.46E-06,-2.00E+00,6.78E-04,9.00E+00,1.44E-06,-1.00E+00,7.76E-04,9.00E+00,2.70E-06,0.00E+00,8.97E-04,9.00E+00,2.45E-06,1.00E+00,9.84E-04,9.00E+00,2.70E-06,2.00E+00
1.81E-09,9.25E+00,3.45E-06,-8.00E+00,1.33E-09,9.25E+00,2.70E-06,-7.00E+00,8.63E-08,9.25E+00,2.70E-06,-6.00E+00,4.14E-05,9.25E+00,1.94E-06,-5.00E+00,1.79E-04,9.25E+00,1.44E-06,-4.00E+00,3.70E-04,9.25E+00,2.45E-06,-3.00E+00,5.57E-04,9.25E+00,2.19E-06,-2.00E+00,6.77E-04,9.25E+00,2.45E-06,-1.00E+00,7.76E-04,9.25E+00,2.70E-06,0.00E+00,8.94E-04,9.25E+00,4.28E-07,1.00E+00,9.82E-04,9.25E+00,2.19E-06,2.00E+00
1.45E-09,9.50E+00,2.19E-06,-8.00E+00,1.88E-09,9.50E+00,1.69E-06,-7.00E+00,8.63E-08,9.50E+00,3.45E-06,-6.00E+00,4.25E-05,9.50E+00,2.95E-06,-5.00E+00,1.79E-04,9.50E+00,4.21E-06,-4.00E+00,3.78E-04,9.50E+00,2.19E-06,-3.00E+00,5.62E-04,9.50E+00,1.69E-06,-2.00E+00,6.78E-04,9.50E+00,1.69E-06,-1.00E+00,7.84E-04,9.50E+00,2.70E-06,0.00E+00,8.91E-04,9.50E+00,2.70E-06,1.00E+00,9.76E-04,9.50E+00,2.70E-06,2.00E+00
1.35E-09,9.75E+00,3.45E-06,-8.00E+00,1.96E-09,9.75E+00,2.95E-06,-7.00E+00,8.59E-08,9.75E+00,3.45E-06,-6.00E+00,4.32E-05,9.75E+00,1.44E-06,-5.00E+00,1.80E-04,9.75E+00,2.45E-06,-4.00E+00,3.85E-04,9.75E+00,1.69E-06,-3.00E+00,5.62E-04,9.75E+00,9.33E-07,-2.00E+00,6.78E-04,9.75E+00,1.94E-06,-1.00E+00,7.88E-04,9.75E+00,2.19E-06,0.00E+00,8.89E-04,9.75E+00,2.19E-06,1.00E+00,9.75E-04,9.75E+00,3.71E-06,2.00E+00
1.34E-09,1.00E+01,2.70E-06,-8.00E+00,1.58E-09,1.00E+01,3.45E-06,-7.00E+00,8.66E-08,1.00E+01,2.70E-06,-6.00E+00,4.31E-05,1.00E+01,2.70E-06,-5.00E+00,1.82E-04,1.00E+01,2.19E-06,-4.00E+00,3.89E-04,1.00E+01,3.20E-06,-3.00E+00,5.63E-04,1.00E+01,2.45E-06,-2.00E+00,6.79E-04,1.00E+01,1.69E-06,-1.00E+00,7.92E-04,1.00E+01,3.20E-06,0.00E+00,8.86E-04,1.00E+01,2.95E-06,1.00E+00,9.77E-04,1.00E+01,2.45E-06,2.00E+00
1.90E-09,1.03E+01,1.94E-06,-8.00E+00,1.50E-09,1.03E+01,2.70E-06,-7.00E+00,8.81E-08,1.03E+01,2.95E-06,-6.00E+00,4.30E-05,1.03E+01,2.70E-06,-5.00E+00,1.87E-04,1.03E+01,2.45E-06,-4.00E+00,3.93E-04,1.03E+01,1.94E-06,-3.00E+00,5.59E-04,1.03E+01,2.45E-06,-2.00E+00,6.76E-04,1.03E+01,3.45E-06,-1.00E+00,7.96E-04,1.03E+01,1.18E-06,0.00E+00,8.86E-04,1.03E+01,3.71E-06,1.00E+00,9.76E-04,1.03E+01,1.69E-06,2.00E+00
2.21E-09,1.05E+01,1.69E-06,-8.00E+00,1.49E-09,1.05E+01,2.19E-06,-7.00E+00,8.89E-08,1.05E+01,2.45E-06,-6.00E+00,4.29E-05,1.05E+01,1.44E-06,-5.00E+00,1.91E-04,1.05E+01,2.95E-06,-4.00E+00,3.92E-04,1.05E+01,2.45E-06,-3.00E+00,5.58E-04,1.05E+01,2.95E-06,-2.00E+00,6.78E-04,1.05E+01,2.70E-06,-1.00E+00,7.93E-04,1.05E+01,2.45E-06,0.00E+00,8.85E-04,1.05E+01,3.45E-06,1.00E+00,9.82E-04,1.05E+01,1.94E-06,2.00E+00
1.71E-09,1.08E+01,2.19E-06,-8.00E+00,2.05E-09,1.08E+01,2.70E-06,-7.00E+00,8.94E-08,1.08E+01,1.94E-06,-6.00E+00,4.29E-05,1.08E+01,3.20E-06,-5.00E+00,1.94E-04,1.08E+01,2.95E-06,-4.00E+00,3.89E-04,1.08E+01,1.94E-06,-3.00E+00,5.57E-04,1.08E+01,2.19E-06,-2.00E+00,6.79E-04,1.08E+01,2.45E-06,-1.00E+00,7.90E-04,1.08E+01,2.95E-06,0.00E+00,8.83E-04,1.08E+01,2.45E-06,1.00E+00,9.86E-04,1.08E+01,2.19E-06,2.00E+00
1.55E-09,1.10E+01,2.70E-06,-8.00E+00,2.37E-09,1.10E+01,2.70E-06,-7.00E+00,9.87E-08,1.10E+01,1.94E-06,-6.00E+00,4.29E-05,1.10E+01,2.45E-06,-5.00E+00,1.96E-04,1.10E+01,2.95E-06,-4.00E+00,3.88E-04,1.10E+01,2.19E-06,-3.00E+00,5.55E-04,1.10E+01,2.95E-06,-2.00E+00,6.91E-04,1.10E+01,2.45E-06,-1.00E+00,7.88E-04,1.10E+01,1.94E-06,0.00E+00,8.81E-04,1.10E+01,2.45E-06,1.00E+00,9.91E-04,1.10E+01,2.95E-06,2.00E+00
1.51E-09,1.13E+01,3.45E-06,-8.00E+00,1.87E-09,1.13E+01,2.45E-06,-7.00E+00,1.11E-07,1.13E+01,2.19E-06,-6.00E+00,4.31E-05,1.13E+01,1.18E-06,-5.00E+00,1.96E-04,1.13E+01,2.45E-06,-4.00E+00,3.87E-04,1.13E+01,2.45E-06,-3.00E+00,5.56E-04,1.13E+01,1.44E-06,-2.00E+00,6.94E-04,1.13E+01,1.69E-06,-1.00E+00,7.85E-04,1.13E+01,2.70E-06,0.00E+00,8.81E-04,1.13E+01,3.20E-06,1.00E+00,9.91E-04,1.13E+01,1.94E-06,2.00E+00
1.88E-09,1.15E+01,1.44E-06,-8.00E+00,1.72E-09,1.15E+01,2.45E-06,-7.00E+00,1.23E-07,1.15E+01,1.94E-06,-6.00E+00,4.31E-05,1.15E+01,2.19E-06,-5.00E+00,1.94E-04,1.15E+01,2.45E-06,-4.00E+00,3.86E-04,1.15E+01,2.70E-06,-3.00E+00,5.56E-04,1.15E+01,2.95E-06,-2.00E+00,6.96E-04,1.15E+01,1.94E-06,-1.00E+00,7.83E-04,1.15E+01,1.44E-06,0.00E+00,8.88E-04,1.15E+01,2.95E-06,1.00E+00,9.92E-04,1.15E+01,3.45E-06,2.00E+00
2.42E-09,1.18E+01,3.71E-06,-8.00E+00,1.68E-09,1.18E+01,9.33E-07,-7.00E+00,1.34E-07,1.18E+01,3.45E-06,-6.00E+00,4.32E-05,1.18E+01,3.20E-06,-5.00E+00,1.94E-04,1.18E+01,2.70E-06,-4.00E+00,3.86E-04,1.18E+01,1.94E-06,-3.00E+00,5.56E-04,1.18E+01,1.44E-06,-2.00E+00,6.96E-04,1.18E+01,3.20E-06,-1.00E+00,7.80E-04,1.18E+01,2.95E-06,0.00E+00,8.92E-04,1.18E+01,2.95E-06,1.00E+00,9.84E-04,1.18E+01,3.20E-06,2.00E+00
2.04E-09,1.20E+01,3.71E-06,-8.00E+00,2.02E-09,1.20E+01,2.70E-06,-7.00E+00,1.46E-07,1.20E+01,1.44E-06,-6.00E+00,4.35E-05,1.20E+01,2.70E-06,-5.00E+00,1.93E-04,1.20E+01,1.94E-06,-4.00E+00,3.86E-04,1.20E+01,2.19E-06,-3.00E+00,5.55E-04,1.20E+01,2.45E-06,-2.00E+00,6.94E-04,1.20E+01,1.69E-06,-1.00E+00,7.83E-04,1.20E+01,2.19E-06,0.00E+00,8.96E-04,1.20E+01,2.45E-06,1.00E+00,9.77E-04,1.20E+01,2.95E-06,2.00E+00
1.79E-09,1.23E+01,2.70E-06,-8.00E+00,2.60E-09,1.23E+01,1.44E-06,-7.00E+00,1.40E-07,1.23E+01,1.94E-06,-6.00E+00,4.49E-05,1.23E+01,2.95E-06,-5.00E+00,1.93E-04,1.23E+01,1.94E-06,-4.00E+00,3.86E-04,1.23E+01,3.20E-06,-3.00E+00,5.59E-04,1.23E+01,2.45E-06,-2.00E+00,6.91E-04,1.23E+01,2.70E-06,-1.00E+00,7.82E-04,1.23E+01,2.95E-06,0.00E+00,8.97E-04,1.23E+01,2.19E-06,1.00E+00,9.78E-04,1.23E+01,3.20E-06,2.00E+00
1.71E-09,1.25E+01,2.95E-06,-8.00E+00,2.22E-09,1.25E+01,2.19E-06,-7.00E+00,1.36E-07,1.25E+01,1.18E-06,-6.00E+00,4.60E-05,1.25E+01,2.70E-06,-5.00E+00,1.93E-04,1.25E+01,2.70E-06,-4.00E+00,3.86E-04,1.25E+01,1.69E-06,-3.00E+00,5.64E-04,1.25E+01,3.20E-06,-2.00E+00,6.88E-04,1.25E+01,2.95E-06,-1.00E+00,7.83E-04,1.25E+01,2.70E-06,0.00E+00,8.97E-04,1.25E+01,3.45E-06,1.00E+00,9.73E-04,1.25E+01,2.70E-06,2.00E+00
1.82E-09,1.28E+01,2.70E-06,-8.00E+00,1.97E-09,1.28E+01,1.94E-06,-7.00E+00,1.33E-07,1.28E+01,3.20E-06,-6.00E+00,4.68E-05,1.28E+01,2.45E-06,-5.00E+00,1.93E-04,1.28E+01,2.70E-06,-4.00E+00,3.90E-04,1.28E+01,2.19E-06,-2.00E+00,5.70E-04,1.28E+01,2.45E-06,-2.00E+00,6.87E-04,1.28E+01,2.95E-06,-1.00E+00,7.81E-04,1.28E+01,2.70E-06,0.00E+00,8.92E-04,1.28E+01,1.94E-06,1.00E+00,9.72E-04,1.28E+01,2.19E-06,2.00E+00
2.59E-09,1.30E+01,3.45E-06,-8.00E+00,1.90E-09,1.30E+01,3.45E-06,-7.00E+00,1.30E-07,1.30E+01,3.45E-06,-6.00E+00,4.78E-05,1.30E+01,3.20E-06,-5.00E+00,1.93E-04,1.30E+01,1.69E-06,-4.00E+00,3.96E-04,1.30E+01,1.94E-06,-2.00E+00,5.75E-04,1.30E+01,2.45E-06,-2.00E+00,6.88E-04,1.30E+01,2.70E-06,-1.00E+00,7.88E-04,1.30E+01,1.94E-06,0.00E+00,8.89E-04,1.30E+01,2.95E-06,1.00E+00,9.68E-04,1.30E+01,2.70E-06,2.00E+00
2.48E-09,1.33E+01,2.70E-06,-8.00E+00,1.98E-09,1.33E+01,2.45E-06,-7.00E+00,1.29E-07,1.33E+01,2.19E-06,-6.00E+00,4.78E-05,1.33E+01,2.95E-06,-5.00E+00,1.93E-04,1.33E+01,2.70E-06,-4.00E+00,4.00E-04,1.33E+01,1.69E-06,-2.00E+00,5.76E-04,1.33E+01,2.45E-06,-2.00E+00,6.85E-04,1.33E+01,2.19E-06,-1.00E+00,7.91E-04,1.33E+01,3.20E-06,0.00E+00,8.86E-04,1.33E+01,1.94E-06,1.00E+00,9.66E-04,1.33E+01,2.45E-06,2.00E+00
2.06E-09,1.35E+01,4.21E-06,-8.00E+00,2.77E-09,1.35E+01,2.45E-06,-7.00E+00,1.27E-07,1.35E+01,2.70E-06,-6.00E+00,4.74E-05,1.35E+01,4.46E-06,-5.00E+00,1.95E-04,1.35E+01,2.45E-06,-4.00E+00,4.03E-04,1.35E+01,2.70E-06,-2.00E+00,5.73E-04,1.35E+01,2.95E-06,-2.00E+00,6.84E-04,1.35E+01,2.95E-06,-1.00E+00,7.96E-04,1.35E+01,2.95E-06,0.00E+00,8.84E-04,1.35E+01,2.95E-06,1.00E+00,9.64E-04,1.35E+01,2.70E-06,2.00E+00
1.94E-09,1.38E+01,1.69E-06,-8.00E+00,2.71E-09,1.38E+01,2.19E-06,-7.00E+00,1.27E-07,1.38E+01,2.70E-06,-6.00E+00,4.73E-05,1.38E+01,2.19E-06,-5.00E+00,1.98E-04,1.38E+01,2.70E-06,-4.00E+00,4.07E-04,1.38E+01,3.45E-06,-2.00E+00,5.68E-04,1.38E+01,2.19E-06,-2.00E+00,6.85E-04,1.38E+01,2.19E-06,-1.00E+00,7.95E-04,1.38E+01,1.44E-06,0.00E+00,8.85E-04,1.38E+01,2.95E-06,1.00E+00,9.65E-04,1.38E+01,1.94E-06,2.00E+00
1.87E-09,1.40E+01,3.45E-06,-8.00E+00,2.25E-09,1.40E+01,3.20E-06,-7.00E+00,1.26E-07,1.40E+01,2.70E-06,-6.00E+00,4.70E-05,1.40E+01,1.69E-06,-5.00E+00,2.00E-04,1.40E+01,2.70E-06,-4.00E+00,4.03E-04,1.40E+01,2.70E-06,-2.00E+00,5.66E-04,1.40E+01,2.45E-06,-2.00E+00,6.84E-04,1.40E+01,1.94E-06,-1.00E+00,7.95E-04,1.40E+01,1.18E-06,0.00E+00,8.83E-04,1.40E+01,2.19E-06,1.00E+00,9.73E-04,1.40E+01,2.19E-06,2.00E+00
2.72E-09,1.43E+01,3.20E-06,-8.00E+00,2.14E-09,1.43E+01,2.45E-06,-7.00E+00,1.25E-07,1.43E+01,2.70E-06,-6.00E+00,4.69E-05,1.43E+01,2.70E-06,-5.00E+00,2.02E-04,1.43E+01,1.69E-06,-4.00E+00,4.00E-04,1.43E+01,2.19E-06,-2.00E+00,5.66E-04,1.43E+01,2.70E-06,-2.00E+00,6.89E-04,1.43E+01,1.18E-06,-1.00E+00,7.93E-04,1.43E+01,2.95E-06,0.00E+00,8.80E-04,1.43E+01,2.95E-06,1.00E+00,9.79E-04,1.43E+01,3.20E-06,2.00E+00
2.98E-09,1.45E+01,3.45E-06,-8.00E+00,2.07E-09,1.45E+01,1.94E-06,-7.00E+00,1.38E-07,1.45E+01,1.69E-06,-6.00E+00,4.67E-05,1.45E+01,2.70E-06,-5.00E+00,2.03E-04,1.45E+01,1.69E-06,-4.00E+00,3.98E-04,1.45E+01,2.45E-06,-2.00E+00,5.65E-04,1.45E+01,2.70E-06,-2.00E+00,6.96E-04,1.45E+01,2.19E-06,-1.00E+00,7.90E-04,1.45E+01,1.69E-06,0.00E+00,8.79E-04,1.45E+01,3.45E-06,1.00E+00,9.80E-04,1.45E+01,1.69E-06,2.00E+00
2.32E-09,1.48E+01,2.95E-06,-8.00E+00,2.90E-09,1.48E+01,1.69E-06,-7.00E+00,1.53E-07,1.48E+01,1.94E-06,-6.00E+00,4.67E-05,1.48E+01,2.45E-06,-5.00E+00,2.02E-04,1.48E+01,2.19E-06,-4.00E+00,3.97E-04,1.48E+01,2.95E-06,-2.00E+00,5.63E-04,1.48E+01,3.71E-06,-2.00E+00,6.99E-04,1.48E+01,1.69E-06,-1.00E+00,7.88E-04,1.48E+01,2.45E-06,0.00E+00,8.81E-04,1.48E+01,1.44E-06,1.00E+00,9.84E-04,1.48E+01,2.70E-06,2.00E+00
2.14E-09,1.50E+01,2.19E-06,-8.00E+00,3.21E-09,1.50E+01,2.45E-06,-7.00E+00,1.68E-07,1.50E+01,2.70E-06,-6.00E+00,4.67E-05,1.50E+01,2.70E-06,-5.00E+00,2.01E-04,1.50E+01,3.20E-06,-4.00E+00,3.96E-04,1.50E+01,3.45E-06,-2.00E+00,5.65E-04,1.50E+01,3.20E-06,-2.00E+00,7.01E-04,1.50E+01,2.45E-06,-1.00E+00,7.87E-04,1.50E+01,2.45E-06,0.00E+00,8.88E-04,1.50E+01,2.45E-06,1.00E+00,9.83E-04,1.50E+01,3.96E-06,2.00E+00
```

After plotting the result looks like:

[image]

Now I want to take a moving average for each GateV(i) and make the plot smoother for DrainI(i) v/s DrainV(i). What is the easiest way to take moving average over DrainI(i) v/s DrainV(i) for each GateV(i)?

Comment: Have you tried searching for ["Moving Average"](https://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=Moving%20average) in the documentation? Did you find [`MovingAverage`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MovingAverage.html)?

Comment: First, use `GatherBy` to group them based on GateV(I), then apply `MovingAverage`.

Comment: Is there a way to use something like MapAt like how I have multiplied the list by 20 in the code. Same way can I apply MovingAverage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dvd5 = Transpose[{idvdnew[[#, All, 1]], 
     GaussianFilter[idvdnew[[#, All, 2]], 7]}] & /@ Range[1, 11];

g1 = ListLinePlot[idvdnew, PlotLegends -> Defer /@ keypairs, 
  Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(DS\)]\)(V)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(d\)]\)(A/mm)"}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 15}, ImageSize -> 400, 
  FrameStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> All]

g2 = ListLinePlot[dvd5, PlotLegends -> Defer /@ keypairs, 
  Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(DS\)]\)(V)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(d\)]\)(A/mm)"}, 
  BaseStyle -> {Thin, Black, FontSize -> 15}, ImageSize -> 400, 
  FrameStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Further, you can compare the two using `Show[g1, g2]`.

Comment: Is there a way to only average over data with VDS > 6 V. It looks like the Gaussian filter is somehow making the curves not start from (0,0)

Comment: The saturation region is where $V_{ds}$ > $V_{gs}$. I can't readily see a way to extract $V_{gs}$ from the dataset. If you can do it, then it would reduce to filtering points in the linear region from each list. Moving averages don't quite align with the first points. In this case the linear region presents a sharp rise and the average would be slightly higher for the first few points.

Comment: I was wondering whether I would have to apply the moving average to each list separately say for Vds> 5V or is there a way to do it on this dataset in a nice way like you have done. Basically, instead of taking the moving average over the whole VDS range just for higher Vds

Comment: Correction: $V_{gs} > V_{TH}$ and $V_{ds} > V_{gs}- V_{TH}$  is the saturation region. So you need two pieces of information. See this [link](https://www.mksinst.com/n/mosfet-physics). For square law devices, the curves towards the top are more distant but in your case they tend to cluster. What process is this?